# threading communication between threads

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, multithreading

So I have a parameterized thread start that initizalizes some NAudio stuff... But I need to have a separate thread tell the NAudio thread to start.  When I try it, it crashes.  How can I implement safe cross-thread communication?

Here's the thread (this class becomes the audio object in the main thread):

```
class Audio
{
    public IWavePlayer OutDevice;
    public WaveStream OutStream;

    public Thread thread;

    public Audio(string file)
    {
        this.thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(InitAudio)); thread.Start(file);
    }

    private void InitAudio(object data) {

        this.OutDevice = new WaveOut();
        this.OutStream = new WaveChannel32(new Mp3FileReader(data.ToString()));
        this.OutDevice.Init(OutStream);
    }
}
```

I need to be able to have my main thread call audio.OutDevice.Play(); but I can't because it's cross-threading and it crashes.  How should I do this?

Comment: I don't know this SDK, but if you were getting this error from a Windows Forms control, I'd say you need to call the Invoke method on the control.

Comment: Can you explain "it crashes" better, perhaps with an example exception?

Comment: It crashes because of two threads sharing the same resource, which causes access violations.

Comment: What exactly is the full exception. Include the output of `ex.ToString()`.

Comment: http://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/236088

Answer (score 0):

You audio playback is using hardware resources and, as is typical, those have to be accessed on the same thread that they were created on. In your code, you left no room for continued access on the thread. I'm surprised you got any sound of that code as your owning thread will shortly go out of scope. It's only because you have those variables tied to the class that anything happened. I personally don't think you need a separate thread in this scenario as I believe that playback is or can be non-blocking. Notwithstanding that, you could follow your plan with something like this (pseudo code):

```
public bool ShouldPlay;
private void InitAudio(object data) {

        var OutDevice = new WaveOut();
        var OutStream = new WaveChannel32(new Mp3FileReader(data.ToString()));
        var OutDevice.Init(OutStream);

        while(!_exitEvent.WaitOne(50ms)){
                 if(ShouldPlay && !OutDevice.IsPlaying)
                        OutDevice.Play();
                 else if(!ShouldPlay && OutDevice.IsPlaying)
                        OutDevice.Stop();
            }
          OutDevice.Stop();
          OutDevice.Dispose();
          OutStream.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: This makes little sense, threads don't create hardware resources.

Comment: To gain further understanding search the web for information on why the GUI frameworks don't allow cross-thread access and what the difference is between STA and MTA threads.

Comment: The reason I have to use a separate thread is because this is coming from an OpenTK/OpenGL application, and if the audio is on the same thread, I get no sound because the computer is spending all its time rendering graphics.  The OpenAL included in OpenTK is absolutely worthless so I also have to use NAudio.  Also in this are you just saying I should have thread 2 check the bool and then thread 1 sets the bool to a value when needed, that's how they communicate?  Wouldn't that still be sharing the bool variable?

Comment: "thread 2 check the bool and then thread 1 sets the bool" -- yes, that's what I'm saying. Your cross-thread exception doesn't have anything to do with sharing variables across threads. That exception is specifically thrown to make sure a certain method is called on a certain thread. I suggest that you read some on multithreading applications. The Head First Java book has a great explanation on it. I assume that the Head First C# book also has good info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want audio buffers to be filled on a background thread, I recommend using the WaveOutEvent class. This will create its own background thread for pulling audio through the pipeline. You can then call Play and Stop from the main thread. The main threading issue you need to beware of in this situation is if you need to implement repositioning within the file you are playing back as the reposition will be happening on the GUI thread while a Read is potentially in progress on another.

For WinForms/WPF apps, the most reliable mechanism is to use WaveOut's windows message callbacks (you'll get this by default if you create WaveOut on a GUI thread). This avoids the need to worry about what thread you are repositioning on. Also, by using the GUI thread for everything, it avoids potential MTA vs STA threading issues, which you will get if you use COM based APIs such as Windows Media API, MediaFoundation, or the DirectX Media Object resampler.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, no shortcuts!  Can you explain how to use the WaveOutEvent please or give me a pointer to documentation?  Thanks!

Comment: WaveOutEvent implements IWaveOut and you use it exactly the same as WaveOut. Call Init, then Play.

Comment: IWaveOut now seems to be IWavePlayer